# Http request body validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, model-validation

It seems straightforward but I just can't figure out a clean and common way to apply different validation rules to http request body.

Binding action parameters to request route or query strings applies the validation data annotations like (required, maxLength, ...etc).

On the other hand I couldn't find a recommended approach to apply similar validations when binding action parameters to request body.

I appreciate if you could guide me to the recommended or most common ways to handle this.

Comment: can you share your code and make it more clear what you are looking for?

Comment: You can validate your Request body with the same validation data annotations you use in request route or query string.